# MySQL index barely speeding up simple query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, ubuntu

I have this table, that contains around 80,000,000 rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`date` date NOT NULL,
`parameters` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`num` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`val1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`val2` int(10) NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
`ref` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`ref`) USING BTREE,
KEY `parameters` (`parameters`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=79092001 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

it's articulated around 2 main columns: "parameters" and "date".
there are around 67,000 possible values for "parameters"
for each "parameters" there are around 1200 rows, each with a different date.
so for each date, there are 67,000 rows.
1200 * 67,000 = 80,400,000.

table size appears as 1.5GB, index size 1.4GB.

now, I want to query the table to retrieve all rows of one "parameters"
(actually I want to do it for each parameter, but this is a good start)

```
SELECT val1 FROM mytable WHERE parameters=1;
```

the first run gives me results in 8 seconds
subsequent runs for different but close values of parameters (2, 3, 4...) are instantaneous

a run for a "far away" value (parameters=1000) gives me results in 8 seconds again.

I did tests running the same query without the index, and got results in 20 seconds, so I guess the index is kicking in as shown by EXPLAIN, but not giving a drastic jump in performances:

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable  | ref  | parameters    | parameters | 3       | const | 1097 |       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-------+
```

but I'm still baffled by the time for such and easy request (no join, directly on the index).

the server is 2 years-old 2 cpu quad core 2.6GHz running Ubuntu, with 4G of RAM.
I've raised the key_buffer parameter to 1G, and have restarted mysql, but noticed no change whatsoever.

should I consider this normal ? or is there something I'm doing wrong ? I get the feeling with the right config the request should be almost immediate.

Comment: it's probably reading from disk. check the OS io stats.

Comment: yes, it seems to be reading from disk, even though it says it is using the index. how can I ensure it does indeed use the index instead of going to disk ?

Comment: it's using the index, but after that, it has to read the records from the disk. assuming you don't have enough memory, which is probably the case. tweaking the config could help a bit...

Comment: should I simply raise the key_buffer parameter to over the size of the index ? or to over the sum of the sizes of table & index ? another config param to consider ?

Comment: it all depends... is this the only table/query you care about? there are many things to consider, eg: mysql partitioning.

Comment: yes, it is the only table I care about. I might do an occasional join on the "parameters" table that contains data related to the parameters, but it's relatively small and I have no issue with it.  it's also the only important query (on parameters and date). I was considering partitioning along the "parameters" column, guess that might help, will try it out. anything to look out for about this ?

Comment: try to free up as much memory as possible. eg: check the query cache size.

Comment: Try to use `pack_keys=1` to have a larger portion of the index in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a covering index, i.e. create an index that includes both of the columns you need.  It won't need the second disk I/O to fetch the values from the main table since the data's right there in the index.

Comment: I actually need more than 2 columns, don't think I should create a 6 columns index !